# QmlProfiler : Plugin initialization failed: Cannot create OpenGL context

Tags: qt, opengl, qml

I use `Qt 6.2.2` in `ubuntu 20.04` and I install OpenGL like this:

```
sudo apt install libgl1-mesa-dev
```

After I install my graphics card driver (NVDI 470.86) I get this error each time I open `QtCreator IDE`.

**why did this happen and how can I fix this?**

**I cant compile examples that use qt quick like [Qt Quick 3D - Custom Materials Example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtquick3d-custommaterial-example.html)**

> QML debugging is enabled. Only use this in a safe environment.
> qt.quick3d.general: Unable to find ideal GL version. QGLXContext:
> Failed to create dummy context QRhiGles2: Failed to create temporary
> context QRhiGles2: Failed to create context Failed to create RHI
> (backend 2) Failed to initialize graphics backend for OpenGL.

**output pictures:**

[image: picture error 1]

[image: picture error 2]

**output from `glxinfo | egrep -i version`**

[image]

Comment: Do other `OpenGL` applications (e.g. glxgears`) work ok?  What's the output from `glxinfo | egrep -i version`?

Comment: the out put is :`server glx version string: 1.4
client glx version string: 1.4
GLX version: 1.4
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 470.103.01
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.60 NVIDIA
OpenGL version string: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 470.103.01
OpenGL shading language version string: 4.60 NVIDIA
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 NVIDIA 470.103.01
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20
    GL_EXT_shader_implicit_conversions, GL_EXT_shader_integer_mix, `

Comment: @G.M.  I have  this problem since I install the driver it seems that Qt cant understand which OpenGL should use but I don't know how should I fix that

Comment: Had the same problem since this morning. I solved it by adding my user to the video group and rebooting: `sudo usermod -a -G video *username*`. Does it work for you?

Comment: Thanks @merosss I will try it , but why this happens for you and why change user group fixed this? I want to know what does qt do each time that qt creator run it seems that it check and look for opengl.why it do that and which path it checks, the  things that I am sure this is new in qt 6 . I didn't have such problem when I use qt 5 .

Comment: Actually, I'm using Qt 5.15. For me the problem generating the "Cannot create OpenGL Context" was related to a general OpenGL failure, where `glxinfo` was giving a "BadRequest" result.

Comment: So why change user group fixed that? Means that  it's strange . Thanks @merosss it fixed and it works now

Comment: I would like to understand it too, but not an expert and cannot answer this question. Let's see if someone can shine some light on this problem by commenting the post. If this worked for you please accept the answer. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had the same problem since this morning. Not sure why this worked (any contribution is appreciated), but I solved it by adding my user to the **video** group and rebooting:

```sh
sudo usermod -a -G video *username*
```

Comment: Doing this indeed did get me past the plugin initialization failure on my Ubuntu 20.04, where the problem started after NVidia driver update. But, it did cause all Qt configurations (.config/QtProject.conf and entire .config/QtProject/) to become unrecognizable for the QtCreator, thus causing losing e.g. all of my cross-compilation envrionments, which is a PITA. So yes, a less intrusive solution would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that **qt creator** save its settings in `/home/username/.config/QtProject` and It understand **OpenGL** from there.

So I delete my `.config` folder and **reboot** my system and let my `OS` create it **again** this Fix my problem but as @merosss said that he change his usermod to the video that was one way because `qt creator` will create it in that path and problem will fix again.

Since I install the NVIDIA driver it seems that Qt cant understand which OpenGL should use and that problem happens.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that this might not help everyone, but in this specific case I was able to solve this by restarting my machine. Worth a try in case it is indeed a one-off issue.

Comment: Well, restarting didn't help me, Deleting `Qt cached and Qt Creator cached` ( in `.config` and `.cache`)+ **restarting** makes it fix because Qt cached settings in `config` and deleting it makes it generate new one again. I think updating my system has a conflict with what it cached.